# Python how to match a character followed by anything without using regrex?

Tags: python, string, match, string-matching

I have a bunch of string look like `aaa -bx` or `aaa -bxx` where `x` would be a digit. Is there any way to mach `bx` or `bxx` without using regrex? I remember there is something like `b_` to match it.

Comment: No.  You can use `string.find('aaa -b')`, and then check if the next character is a digit, but there's no "matching" in Python without using a regex.

Comment: Without using regrex? How about using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string methods.

Matching literal `aaa -b` followed by digits:

```
def match(s):
    start = 'aaa -b'
    return s.startswith(start) and s[len(start):].isdigit()

match('aaa -b33')
# True
```

If you rather want to check if the part after the last `b` are digits, use `s.rsplit('b')[-1].isdigit()`